# Loop through a directory and its sub-directories files in liquid

Tags: loops, liquid

I am a newbie to liquid templating language, regarding the website am working on it's powered by jekyll, we publish posts and sometimes series of posts so we make a sub directory for series posts in `_posts` directory. Can I loop through all files in the directory `_posts` and its sub directories given that I don't know their names or number ? 
My file tree :
`root
   |
   _posts/
      |
      post1.md
      post2.md
      series_name/
         |
         post3.md`

Comment: Are these files on your local machine? You can access and loop through them with any language or script. I don't understand what it has anything to do with Jekyll? It's just a static-site generator

Comment: thanks for your reply, you are right I'll edit the question, sorry for misunderstanding,  i can't figure out how to loop through the files in liquid, yes files are on my local machine.

Comment: Can this [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17446472/how-to-list-files-in-a-directory-with-liquid) be what you're looking for? Sounds similar

Comment: thanks for your help, I saw the question but it is not what am asking about, i want to loop through all files within `_posts` directory and its sub directories as if `_posts` directory has no sub directories .. Is there a way i can do it using liquid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer to your question is **YES**.

## Solution

The [Jekyll documentation](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/posts/#displaying-an-index-of-posts) guides you through displaying an index of all your `_posts`. Specifically, you will want something like the following:

```
<ul>
  {% for post in site.posts %}
    <li>
      <a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

I have tested this with subdirectories.

### Explanation

Jekyll appears to ignore any folder structure inside of `_posts` while generating your `_site`. My `_site` has the following structure:

```
_posts/
    |
    post1.md
    subdirectory/
        |
        post2.md
_site/
    |
     2015/
        |
        08/
            |
            05/
                |
                post1.html
                post2.html
```

You can clearly see here that the subdirectory does not appear anywhere in your final site.

### Extra credit

You can retrieve the original directory structure using `{{ post.path }}` and some careful string manipulation. However, at this point it's probably easier to just set the `Category` attribute in your [YAML front matter](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/frontmatter/). The category attribute can be retrieved with `{{category}}`.

*Purely as an academic exercise, I went ahead and retrieved the directory.*

```
  {% capture directory %}
      {% assign path = post.path | remove_first:'_posts/' | split:'/' %}
      {% for folder in path %}
          {% unless forloop.last %}
              {{ folder }}/
          {% endunless %}
      {% endfor %}
  {% endcapture %}
  Directory: {{directory}}
```

You can decide if this is useful.

Answer (score 1):

I really dont know if this is helpfully but I will write down my solution anyway, only because I didnt really found a quick explanation.

To iterate through files you'll only need to add the following code snippet in your `_config.yml` file:

```
collections:
    articles:
              output: true
```

After that you can call a for loop like this:

**Note**: Beware that you have your files in the root directory, in this example e.g. `_articles/article01.md`.

**Example**

```
{% for article in site.articles %}
    {{ forloop.index  }}yes
{% endfor %}
```

You can see the behavior in this tutorial [video](https://learn.cloudcannon.com/jekyll/looping-in-liquid/) but without the comment to include the collection tag in the `_config.yml` file